# Create a conda environment offline

Tags: python, anaconda, offline, environment, conda

I have Anaconda2 installed on a remote machine where there is no internet connection.

I am trying to create a `conda` environment where I would run my application,when I tried :

```
    conda create -n nameofmyenv anaconda
```

but since it fetches packages from api.anaconda.com, it is not working and hangs at `"Fetching packages" (no internet connection)`, so I set ***offline=True*** in a .condarc file (under anaconda2 directory), but no luck either (*Error: `package missing in current linux-64 channels`*)

I then tried :

```
    conda create --name nameofmyenv --clone root
```

with both `offline=True/False`, it does create a folder `nameofmyenv` under `anaconda2/envs` but there is only one file in it which is the .condarc one. In the terminal and with this cmd, I got a KeyError for the package "`sockjs-tornado-1.0.1-py27_0.tar.bz2`" like so :

[image]

even though this package exists in the `anaconda2/pkgs` folder.

I have already seen this [script](https://github.com/ilanschnell/misc/blob/master/conda/c2r.py), but I'm not sure what to do with it exactly ? I created a file `c2r.py` in the anaconda2 folder and tried to run this script but I think I'm missing something..

**Has anyone already tried to create a conda environment offline? If so how did you do it? ^^**

Thank you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install a conda environment when offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729731/how-can-i-install-a-conda-environment-when-offline)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way to get my code working without dependency issues, which is to clear the pythonpath variable, and then make it point to the python of Anaconda like so :
`export PYTHONPATH="~/anaconda2/bin/python"`.

This way I have no import problems on the remote machine with no internet connection (since I mainly use libraries already in anaconda)

Maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37391824/simply-use-python-anaconda-without-internet-connection?lq=1) can be helpful to others who want to create a conda environment offline using channels ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Installing conda packages offline](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/installing-with-conda.html#installing-conda-packages-offline)

To install conda packages offline, run: `conda install /path-to-package/package-filename.tar.bz2/`

If you prefer, you can create a /tar/ archive file containing many conda packages and install them all with one command: `conda install /packages-path/packages-filename.tar`