# Create conda environment on local server?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I wanted to create an environment on my local server like `conda create -n py3`, but conda tries to connect to the remote repository:

```
Fetching package metadata ...Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64/
```

How can I create environment on my local server in offline-mode?

```
Current conda install:

               platform : linux-64
          conda version : 4.2.9
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.2.9
    conda-build version : 2.0.2
         python version : 3.5.2.final.0
       requests version : 2.11.1
       root environment : /opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-4.2.0  (writable)
    default environment : /opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-4.2.0
       envs directories : /opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-4.2.0/envs
          package cache : /opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-4.2.0/pkgs
           channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64/
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
            config file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: `conda create` also has an `--offline` flag: https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-create.html Please search the documentation/do some research before posting here :-)

Comment: @darthbith Even when I add `--offline` in this case I got a error: `PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current linux-64 channels: - python 3.5*`

Comment: I refere to this post to answer my question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729731/how-can-i-install-a-conda-environment-when-offline?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: What exact command are you using? Are you specifying any packages to be installed in the environment?

Comment: @nekomatic did you have the same problem?

Comment: No, I'm trying to understand your problem! `conda` will try to connect to the remote repository by default unless you tell it not to with the `--offline` flag. The error you report above suggests `conda` can't find a local copy of the necessary package. But without knowing exactly what you're asking it to do it's hard to help.

Comment: @nekomatic I added the `--offline` flag as mentionned above, the error I got has came from the version of Conda I used `4.2.9`, check this issue: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/4267 , so to fix this problem I do install a new version of Conda `4.4.0`

Comment: @nekomatic back to the present question I think that `--offline` has answed my issue, but I faced a other issue so I post a new question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49777621/have-3-x-and-3-y-anaconda-version-on-offline-mode

Comment: Thank you @nekomatic, I do appriciate your help, I hope this contribution help other people, I try to do my best