# Anaconda Python support for isolated environments

Tags: python, anaconda, data-science

I just wanted to know if Anaconda Python has any support for isolated environments... There's nothing about it in the internet and right now I'm working on an isolated environment.

Thanks!

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729731/how-can-i-install-a-conda-environment-when-offline) is repeated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install a conda environment when offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729731/how-can-i-install-a-conda-environment-when-offline)